How to convert this mongo shell to java
I'm trying to convert this mongo shell to Mongotemplate, but I can't find any way to do it.
Here is the shell：
db.userCustomSetting.deleteMany({
    $expr: {$regexMatch: {input: { $toString: "$_id" },regex: /.*0000$/}}
});

I tried this：
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(".*0000$");
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").regex(regexPattern));`

But it didn't work.

the type of the primary key is  ObjectId

Regex is for matching strings. So, you may want to convert the ObjectId to a string and try. (b) "But it didn't work." Is there an error?

Yes you are right, I want to use mongoTemplate to complete a fuzzy query on a primary key that is objectId type

Note that such a query will not use the default index on the_id field. (a) You can try using a aggregate query where you can transform the ObjectId to a string and then do the regex. (b) You can possibly try executing it using other ways, like MongoRepository with @Query or @Aggregate, (c) MongoTemplate#executeCommand. All these will require the conversion to string using the ObjectId#toString method and be aware  of no index usage.

@Query("{" +
"  $expr: {" +
"    $regexMatch: {" +
"      input: { $toString: "$_id" }," +
"      regex: /.*0000$/" +
"    }" +
"  }" +
"}")
List find();             Success, thank you very much for your answer
